# segmentation fault on bool variable if statement c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, segmentation-fault, boolean

I have a function which returns a bool variable. Then I used 2 if statements to print something depending on if the bool variable is true or false. The system prints out segmentation fault instead which is strange since I declared the variable at the beggining as false, so it would make more sense that the program always printed the false statement. The only thing I can think of is that maybe I write the if statement incorrectly?? is there a certain way to write an if statement for a boolean variable?

Here is the input

Please enter name of the input file: 40.txt
Please enter the prefered sum 1000

Here is the output

There were 1600 checks made to find the products of your desired sum and
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Here are the if statements but I will add the whole code below

```
if(!found)
{
    cout << " the program did not find any matches. try again. ";
}
if(found)
{
cout << "the two numbers that add to your sum are " << n1 << " and " << n2 << ". These were found in position " << pos1 << " and " << pos2;
}
```

Here's the whole code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int x, i, n1, n2, pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, accesses = 0;

int readSortedArray(int array[20], int count, istream& infile)
{
    count = 0;
    while (infile >> array[count])
    {
        count++;

    }

    return count;
}

bool findproducts(int array[20],
                  int& n1,
                  int& n2,
                  int count,
                  int& accesses,
                  bool found,
                  int& pos1,
                  int& pos2)
{
    int sum;
    cout << "Please enter the prefered sum ";
    cin >> sum;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        pos1++;
        n1 = array[i];
        pos2 = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < count; x++)

        {
            pos2++;
            accesses++;
            n2 = array[x];
            if (sum == n1 + n2)
            {
                found = true;
                i = count;
                x = count;
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[20];
    int answer, count = 0;
    bool found = false;

    std::string input_filename;
    ifstream infile;

    cout << "Please enter name of the input file: ";
    cin >> input_filename;
    infile.open(input_filename.c_str());
    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "Could not open input file one\n";
        return 0;
    }

    count = readSortedArray(array, count, infile);

    found = findproducts(array, n1, n2, count, accesses, found, pos1, pos2);

    cout << "There were " << accesses << " checks made to find the products of your desired sum and" << endl;

    if (!found)
    {
        cout << " the program did not find any matches. try again. ";
    }
    if (found)
    {
        cout << "the two numbers that add to your sum are " << n1 << " and " << n2 << ". These were found in position " << pos1 << " and " << pos2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Stuff I noticed while formatting: `findproducts` doesn't always return. `found` parameter in `findproducts` should probably be a reference or removed. Both are flagged by the compiler with a reasonable warning level. Turn on warnings. Heed them. A warning means code is syntactically correct, but probably logically wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason you are declaring a bunch of your variables globally and not in main? You are passing them to the function anyways, it would probably help you understand the scoping better.

Comment: Scope is for the weak. Real men use `goto`, ignore compiler warnings, refuse to use a debugger, and hammer nails with their forehead.

Comment: what is the content of `input_filename` ?

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40

Comment: `findproduct` returns `true` if it finds a match, but it never returns `false`.

Comment: i tried having it do that too. no difference.

Comment: I have fixed the program (by just moving that part into the function so I dont have to pass the variable ha) but it still says segmentation fault at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read 40 numbers into an array[20]. Change all the 20's to 40's (or make that a constant) and the segmentation fault should go away. Probably it would be a good idea to add a clause to `while (infile >> array[count])` that checks count is less than the array's length and then && does what you have in the parentheses. The ideas in the comments are still legitimate as far as making the program run correctly and understandably, but assigning beyond the end of the array is the likely source of your segmentation fault.

Comment: also get rid of the unused variable answer. But mostly, besides changing those 20s to 40s add return false; before the final } of findProducts